"error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: " when class put before public class
In a java code if I put the non-public class before public class this error pops up.
"error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: className"
ref1
But, if I put it after the public class, it does not.
Here I put the class after the public class and it does not show any error.
ref2
This seems to be the case with my compiler alone because I saw creators on YT doing the same thing and it works for them.
Though I know it's not a major issue and I can just create the class below the public class, I would still like to know why it happens. Does it have something to do with my PC or is there some setting I need to toggle?
Thanks!
Here's a basic code for reference:
Working(Hello World):
        public class refError {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
               System.out.println("Hello World");
           }
        }
        class ABC {
            ABC() {
                System.out.println("Constructor");
            }
        }

Not Working(error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: ABC):
        class ABC {
            ABC() {
                System.out.println("Constructor");
            }
        }
        public class refError {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        }


1 - Why are you stuffing multiple top level classes into one file? Don't do that. 2 - What does PHP have to do with this?

Welcome to SO! Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include your code and errors as code-formatted text.

I've fixed it. Thanks for the advice @AndrewYim.

@ElliottFrisch I'm sorry if I marked PHP into it. I tried to add "error" tag and pressed enter.

Note that compiling and running with java has different semantics to compiling with javac and running with java, or compiling and running with an IDE.  But either way, stuffing multiple top-level classes into one file is a bad idea.  (Whether you want to do it or not.)

To the folks who closed this as a duplicate. First time you marked it as a duplicate of the "generic" Q&A which (as far as I can tell) doesn't actually mention this particular manifestation of the problem.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/) ,  Then you closed is as a duplicate of a question with a terrible title that is Closed AND has a delete vote on it.  Neither of those was a good choice.

The behavior is explained by the manual entry for the java command.  (Java 17)

In source-file mode, execution proceeds as follows:
The class to be executed is the first top-level class found in the source file. It must contain a declaration of the standard public static void main(String[]) method.

(Emphasis added ...)
Assuming1 that you are running the code as follows:
$ java refError.java


Your "working" example works because the first class (refError) has the required main method.

Your "not working" example doesn't works because the first class (ABC) does not have the required main method.



Note that this behavior is different to what you will get by compiling first using javac.  Assuming that both classes are in a file called "refError.java"
$ javac refError.java
$ java refError

will output "Hello world" in both cases.  The javac command emits a separate ".class" file for each class, and then the java command finds the ".class" file for the refError class.

This is not due to any differences (or bugs!) in compilers.  And it is not due to incorrect installation or settings.  It is simply that you are using the tools in differently to what they were doing in that video.  (Apparently ...)
And this is yet another reason why most people experienced in Java say it is a bad idea to stuff multiple top level classes into a single file.  Notwithstanding what you might see in some YouTube video.

1 - There is evidence that this is what the OP did in the linked images.
